# Batch file output

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that reads through a text file to obtain document locations, it then goes and copies the physical file to a local folder. What I need to include is if the physical file doesn't exist I need to output the document details from the text file to another file so I have a list of missing document. I hope this makes sense.

Here's my batch file contents

```
SET destfolder=e:\data
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (e:\cn_documents.csv) DO COPY "%%a" "%destfolder%\%%~nxa"
```

Comment: Okay - so if I'm reading this right, you're wanting to create a "log file" of locations that were missed in this for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like all you need is to simply check if the file exists before copying. This can be done with an `IF EXIST` condition.

```
SET destfolder=e:\data
SET DoesNotExistList="E:\DoesNotExist.txt"

REM Reset the not exist list so it doesn't pile up from multiple runs.
ECHO The following files were not found > %DoesNotExistList%

FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (e:\cn_documents.csv) DO (
    REM Check if the file exists.
    IF EXIST "%%a" (
        REM It does exist, copy to the destination.
        COPY "%%a" "%destfolder%\%%~nxa"
    ) ELSE (
        REM It does not exist, note the file name.
        ECHO %%a>>%DoesNotExistList%
    )
)
```

Comment: Many Thanks Jason, that was exactly what I needed